# AspNet.Identity.Core : how to create a user manually - HashPassword

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, password-hash

I have a .NET core app, it works perfectly.

But I need to create a batch of new users, by inserting directly into the database.
The problem now is that when I try to login, it failed...

I suspect a problem with the hashed password.

I use the following code to generate my hash and security stamp:

```
_user.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");
_user.UserName = _userName;
_user.Email = _email;
var hasher = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();
IdentityUser identityUser = new IdentityUser(Guid.Parse(_user.Id), _userName, _email);
_user.PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(identityUser, _password);
```

From my understanding, it should work, but do you have any idea to debug / fix this issue ?

Comment: you don't need to hash the password (it is done automatically), unless you have another password you use.. usually you use the UserManager to create a user with the method CreateAsync() that takes a user and their password as arguments. So you don't need to create an id either. But maybe you need something else?

Comment: Thanks, but I do not use the Identity framework. I wish to insert directly into the database from a batch. All I need is to generate a correct hash.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't use custom VerifyHashedPassword method.**

From the source code of `PasswordHasher` below, we can see `VerifyHashedPassword()` can verify automatically with `hashedPassword` from DB and original input password.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
{
  internal static class Crypto
  {
    private const int PBKDF2IterCount = 1000;
    private const int PBKDF2SubkeyLength = 32;
    private const int SaltSize = 16;

    public static string HashPassword(string password)
    {
      if (password == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
      byte[] salt;
      byte[] bytes;
      using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 16, 1000))
      {
        salt = rfc2898DeriveBytes.Salt;
        bytes = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(32);
      }
      byte[] inArray = new byte[49];
      Buffer.BlockCopy((Array) salt, 0, (Array) inArray, 1, 16);
      Buffer.BlockCopy((Array) bytes, 0, (Array) inArray, 17, 32);
      return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
    }

    public static bool VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string password)
    {
      if (hashedPassword == null)
        return false;
      if (password == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
      byte[] numArray = Convert.FromBase64String(hashedPassword);
      if (numArray.Length != 49 || (int) numArray[0] != 0)
        return false;
      byte[] salt = new byte[16];
      Buffer.BlockCopy((Array) numArray, 1, (Array) salt, 0, 16);
      byte[] a = new byte[32];
      Buffer.BlockCopy((Array) numArray, 17, (Array) a, 0, 32);
      byte[] bytes;
      using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 1000))
        bytes = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(32);
      return Crypto.ByteArraysEqual(a, bytes);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
    private static bool ByteArraysEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
      if (object.ReferenceEquals((object) a, (object) b))
        return true;
      if (a == null || b == null || a.Length != b.Length)
        return false;
      bool flag = true;
      for (int index = 0; index < a.Length; ++index)
        flag &= (int) a[index] == (int) b[index];
      return flag;
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Test Codes**

```
    public static User user = new User();

    [Route("/")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //register a user
        if(user != null) {
            //test data
            user.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            user.UserName = "test";
            user.Email = "test@x.com";
            user.Password = "password";

            var hasher = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();
            IdentityUser identityUser = new IdentityUser(user.Id.ToString());

            user.PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(identityUser, user.Password);
        }

        //... save user to DB

        return View();
    }
```

**Login controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            //... Here are codes get Id by email from DB

            var hasher = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();
            IdentityUser identityUser = new IdentityUser(user.Id.ToString());

            if (PasswordVerificationResult.Failed == hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(identityUser,user.PasswordHash, login.Password))
               ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "password is wrong");

        }
        else
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "email or password invalid");

        return PartialView("_LoginModalPartial", login);
    }
```

> Test of result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use

```cs
private readonly RandomNumberGenerator _rng;

public virtual string HashPassword(TUser user, string password)
{
    if (_compatibilityMode == PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2)
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(HashPasswordV2(password, _rng));
    }
    else
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(HashPasswordV3(password, _rng));
    }
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.passwordhasher-1.hashpassword?view=aspnetcore-3.1

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs#L96

Read more: https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-asp-net-core-identity-passwordhasher/#hashing-new-passwords

Comment: Thanks, but it is already what I'm doing, right? The problem is that when I try to login, it failed!